# How to read a matrix from a file and assign to 2 dimensional array(Matrix) declared in bash script using awk

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

I have a problem with printing when i `echo` matrix's elements, when i uncomment  in first loops `echo ${matrix[$i,$j]}`, program works correctly ,but when i want to print `${matrix[$i,$j]}`in second loops the output is empty characters.The goal is to read matrix from a file and assign to my matrix declared in script.

```
function readMatrixFromFile() {
        local file="$1"
        declare -A matrix
        local num_rows=$(awk 'NR==1 {print $3}' $1)
        local num_colums=$(awk 'NR==2 {print $3}' $1)

        for ((i=3;i<=num_rows+2;i++)) do
                for ((j=1;j<=num_colums;j++)) do
                        k=i-2
                        matrix[$k,$j]=$(awk -v row=$i -v col=$j 'NR==row {print $col}' $file)
                        #echo ${matrix[$i,$j]}
                done
        done


        for ((i=1;i<=num_rows;i++)) do
               for ((j=1;j<=num_colums;j++)) do
                       echo ${matrix[$i,$j]}
               done
               echo
        done

}

function Main() {
        readMatrixFromFile Matrix3.txt
}

Main
```

Here is Matrix3.txt

[image]

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                           

declare -A m

read_matrix() {
    local i=0
    local line
    local j
    # Ignore the first 2 lines containing size of the matrix
    read rows
    read cols
    while read -r line; do
        j=0
        # split on spaces
        for v in `echo $line`; do
            m[$i,$j]="$v"
            j=$((j+1))
        done
        i=$((i+1))
    done
}

read_matrix < matrix.file

echo ${m[1,2]}
```

Comment: i have updated my question, can you please check it ))

Comment: i have to save matrix sizes, because when i multiply the matrices i have not to read all the matrix, i will just read the sizes of the matrix

Comment: @Levon Is there a reason you are doing matrix computations in the shell and not in some other language or framework that actually supports matrixes and matrix algebra natively (such as Octave)?

Comment: @Kusalananda No there isn't any reason, i am just train my brain :)
And study bash-script

Comment: But i can't understand why my echo not working, when i want to print matrix's elements?

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a local vs. global variable scoping issue, I believe.

I found a similar 'empty' array when trying to pull data - but determined that the inside-a-function-declared array's contents were only retrievable within the function, since I defined there (which the original post shows and is exactly my situation)

Note: you can put a function before the MAIN part of your script and it won't be a problem as it's use is tied to the function call further down

Load in the table of data into a two dimensional array
So that it can become actionable within a loop in the MAIN
MAIN PART OF BASH SCRIPT - THE BELOW IS EXECUTED BEFORE THE ABOVE
SINCE THE ABOVE IS COMPLETELY ENCLOSED WITHIN THE FUNCTION DEFINESCOPE

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Let's first define the function before the Main Body of Script"

function DEFINESCOPE {

    for ((Row=1;Row<=num_rows;Row++)) 
    do

      for ((Col=1;Col<=num_columns;Col++)) 
      do

        RowData=`cat $STATSFile | head -${Row} | tail -1 | awk -v c1=$Col -F\, '{print $c1}' | sed -e 's/"//g'`

        matrix[$Row,$Col]=$RowData

        echo "Checking to see if the loaded data can be pulled: Matrix[$Row,$Col] = ${matrix[$Row,$Col]}"

     done

   done
} 

echo "End of Function DEFINESCOPE"

echo "Start of MAIN part of script"

STATSFile="STATSFile"
cat $STATSFile
declare -A matrix

echo "THIS IS THE FUNCTION CALL WHERE THE DATA IS LOADED per the above code"

DEFINESCOPE

echo "NOW TO PULL THE DATA WHILE IN THE MAIN PART OF THE SCRIPT"

echo "In this case I want to start by skipping over the first 3 columns and then walk the rows for each column"

StartRow="1"
StartCol="4"
Row=$StartRow
Col=$StartCol

for ((Col=${StartCol};Col<=num_columns;Col++)) 
do
    Row=$StartRow
    echo "Current Position: Matrix[$Row,$Col] = ${matrix[${Row},${Col}]}"
    ReportType=${matrix[$Row,$Col]}

    echo "============================================="
    echo "Walking NEW Report Type: $ReportType"
    for ((Row=${StartRow};Row<=num_rows;Row++)) 
    do

        echo "Using a CASE statement instead of a bunch of if.then.else.fi..."
        echo "Pull Metric Data for C/H/M/L Severity Row Counts"
        echo "Determine which type of row we're examining and then assign values"

         case "${matrix[$Row,1]}" in
             Critical)
                 Criticals=${matrix[$Row,$Col]}
                 echo "Setting Severity Count for Criticals: $Criticals"
                 ;;
             Highs)
                 Highs=${matrix[$Row,$Col]}
                 echo "Setting Severity Count for Highs: $Highs"
                 ;;
             Mediums)
                 Mediums=${matrix[$Row,$Col]}
                 echo "Setting Severity Count for Mediums: $Mediums"
                 ;;
             Lows)
                 Lows=${matrix[$Row,$Col]}
                 echo "Setting Severity Count for Lows: $Lows"
                 ;;
             *)
                 echo "Case *): Does not match: matrix[Row,1]: ${matrix[$Row,1]}"
                 ;;
         esac
         echo "Current Data Position: matrix[Row,Col]: ${matrix[$Row,$Col]}"
         echo "Current Row Position: matrix[Row,1]: ${matrix[$Row,1]}"
     done
done

echo "Thus, I moved the 'declare' statement to the main part of the bash"
echo "script, prior to the function call, loaded the data in the function," echo "and then I was then able to pull data from the array when in the main part of the script."

echo "Bottom Line: declare your array in the main part of the script, before you call a function/subroutine to load or output array data."
```

Comment: The answer is kinda messy. You should update it with proper formatting so that it is easy to discern what is code and what isn't.